# how to jump to a file already open using vim quickfix

Tags: vim, makefile

When I compile in `vim` using `:make` the quickfix windows displays the error list.

Suppose one of the errors is contained in one of the files already open in my VIM session:
is there anyway to click or select the error and jumping to a file already open instead of changing the file I am currently looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set switchbuf=useopen,usetab
```

is what you want. See `:help switchbuf` for information and my answer to your previous question for an illustration.